# The Array.Rank on C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm studying about the array. I wondering about Array.Rank, here is example:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      int[] array1 = new int[10];
      int[,] array2= new int[10,3];  
      int[][] array3 = new int[10][]; 

      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} dimension(s)", 
                        array1.ToString(), array1.Rank);
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} dimension(s)", 
                        array2.ToString(), array2.Rank);
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} dimension(s)", 
                        array3.ToString(), array3.Rank);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       System.Int32[]: 1 dimension 
//       System.Int32[,]: 2 dimension 
//       System.Int32[][]: 1 dimension
```

My question is: why does `array3.Rank` return 1 dimension but not 2?

Comment: Because it only has one dimension. It's a 1-D array that contains other arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Int32[][]` this **is** 1 dimension, this is an array of array, not a 2D array : `System.Int32[,]`

Answer (score 2):

> A jagged array (an array of arrays) is a one-dimensional array; the
>   value of its Rank property is 1.

Read more about [jagged arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)